# Displaying text over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text over image, however, it does't seem to work. Live preview: http://vexato.com Scroll to the Portfolio section and if you hover the first image, it will not show the text. However, after debugging, I noticed that it does show it but it is invisible. How do I fix that?

Code specific to this problem:

```css
.portfolio {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.project-item {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.project-info {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.project-item:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.project-item:hover .project-info {
  opacity: 1;
}
#portfolio-projects {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
#portfolio-projects li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul id="portfolio-projects">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
    <div class="project-info">
      <h5>Project Name</h5>
      <p>Click here to view.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="project-item mix category-2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense. The images have a 25% width, but the li should have 25% and the images should have 100% (of the li).

Comment: @Thomas I know, but it didn't work for me that way... :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your current code is a descendant selector and will work only when `.project-info` is a child of `.project-item`

**Solution:**

You need to select the sibling element with `+` operator.

```
.project-item:hover + .project-info {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the solution. :)

Comment: what do I use if the class which I wanted to set opacity was a parent class?

Comment: There is no CSS class for parent.  https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/apply-class-to-parent-if-child-div-contains-class/

Comment: I mean, like when I hover on the positions of text on the box, it doesn't show the black background. How would I fix that?

Comment: Like this? .project-info:hover {
    background: black;
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: If you see the demo again, and if you view hover on the first item, where there should be text, it wont add a dark layer on it. But it does if I do it when hovering on areas where there is no text. How do I fix that?

Comment: This looks like a different situation. Would you mind opening a new question?

Comment: Yeah sure @ManojKumar

Comment: oh god, I can't because of the timer. I can only posts questions every 90 minutes. :/

Answer (score -2):

opacity for .project-info is set to 0, on hover change to 1.

Comment: -1 In his code, there is this: `.project-item:hover .project-info {
    opacity: 1;
}` so, he is already doing this, you just didn't read his code carefully enough